# End of AVICII's The Nights: Why is the end of the sound wave not centered around zero?

Tags: electronic-music, folk, sound

This is the end of AVICII's [The Nights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nights) ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtF6Jej8yb4)) viewed in Audacity:

[image]

Question: Is there a particular purpose for keeping the wave out of the center?

I guess it does not change the sound (or at least not in a way that humans can hear), but maybe there are merits I have not thought about? Or maybe it is just for the visual effect of the diaphragms coming back to position after the music stops, for instance? Or to prevent people/programs from cutting the track as soon as the music stops, maybe?

Comment: It's not clear how did you get a youtube track playing in audacity... is the method reliable to begin with? Does the recording method do the same for different tracks? But the main question is **why would it necessarily be centred**? A lot of classic waveforms, especially when you work with harmonization are nor centred.

Comment: I don't know the reason for this perticular track, but I used to work on some audio effects that consisted on "un-centerize" a waveform in order to create harmonics, for example, take a sine wave and replace negative by zero.

Comment: @Bebs: Did you left the waveform uncenterized on purpose? Or did you just left it like this because centering it would waste a few minutes of work for no noticeable benefit?

Comment: In my case, I didn't think about it back then... but to center the signal, it is needed to know its mean. In real time applications, the mean can vary so re-centering the signal (i.e. removing its mean which is not constant) would require processing costs and could actually add an unwanted audible effect.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, people don't intentionally un-center the waveform. They apply wanted sound effects that have side effects to un-center the waveform. Un-centering is a consequence, not a purpose.